# Qt equivalent to winapi InterlockedIncrement?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

i try to find equivalent in Qt c++ to winapi InterlockedIncrement
i was reading : 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qatomicint.html
but i didnt understand it , can someone please give me simple example

Comment: explain a bit what properties of `InterlockedIncrement` you want, such that people who only know Qt can answer, not only people who know both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InterlockedIncrement()` generates a full memory barrier (or fence) to ensure that memory operations are completed in order (MSDN documentation.) It returns the new value.

In Qt, this translates to `QAtomicInt::fetchAndAddOrdered(1) + 1`. For example:

```
QAtomicInt atomInt(15);
int n = atomInt.fetchAndAddOrdered(1) + 1; // n == 16, atomInt == 16
```